# Linkedin API integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkedin-api

**Question:** Is there a procedure to get the linkedin access token using the Linkedin API key and Linkedin Client Secret key using C# or ASP.net?

**Requirement:** I want to integrate Linkedin functionality in my website and store the information of user in my MSSQL database.

Comment: have you looked at LinkedIn API Developer Documentation? https://developer.linkedin.com/docs

Comment: There is very well documentation  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/

Answer (score 0):

Super late answer, but for anybody seeing this now, [LinkedIn now has Authentication docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow).

There are no SDKs, but it's a relatively easy flow to implement yourself :)